# In Visual Studio Community (for Unity) how to get automatic TAB with "carriage return line feed" in a comment section /* */?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, text, format, comments

It worked before, but i did update and reset some settings and now it make me lost few secondes each times.
When I write comments like this in a C# file :

```
/*
        writting some comments... ""PRESS ENTER TO CREATE NEW LINE COMMENT""
""NEW LINE START AT EXTREM LEFT AND I WOULD LIKE IT START AT SAME TAB LEVEL AS UPPER LINE""  
*/
```

So how to get it work again ? hope im clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the “Indenting” option of C# > Tabs from “Smart” or “None” to “Block”.

**Solution:**

Go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Tabs > Indenting > select “Block”.

[image]

Besides, there is another solution, and will set the format of comment as below:

```
/*
* write something
* write something
*/
```

For this method, please go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced > Editor Help > check “Insert * at the start of new lines when writing /* */ comments” checkbox.

[image]

Hope this helps.